# Name of Georgian lemonade?

Tags: georgia-country, food-and-drink, identify-this

This summer I ate in a Georgian restaurant in Krakow, Poland. The food was really good, but especially tasty was the Georgian lemonade. I can't remember the name, but a friend of mine is going to travel near to Georgia too and I want to recommend this lemonade to him.

All I can remember is that it smelled very similar to sprite and it is in a violet bottle with Georgian letters on it. Does anybody know its name?

Comment: Hmm Georgia is most famous for its mineral water, especially Borjomi. By hunting on the net I find mention of a syrup based softdrink called ლაღიძის წყალი (laghidzis tsqali) or [Lagizde water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagidze_water) in English. It comes in a varity of flavours but I couldn't find any photos with a violet bottle.

Comment: What colour was the drink itself? Clear like sprite? What about the flavour? Like lemonade or like Sprite or something different?

Comment: The drink itself was clear like sprite and also tasted like sprite. Then Lagizde water is kinda close, but the bottle was more violett.

Comment: What year were you there? It appears some brands change colours over the years...

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Well that rules out the grape flavoured Natakhtari which was a purplish drink in a clear bottle and the closest I can find so far.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: If it was clear like sprite I guess it was Lemon flavor

Comment: yes that could be the flavour

Comment: I did some research and found the homepage of the restaurant where I got this lemonade: http://www.chaczapuri.pl/

Comment: @Roflcoptr: The Lemonade on the front page is Natakhtari

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah yes! you must have been in [Gruzinski Czaczapuri](http://www.natakhtari.ge/?action=page&page_id=68&pageon=68&lang=eng)!
I am also looking for this lemonade, especially the pear flavour, I think this might be it!
[image]

Comment: This is it. The second from the left.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the two most major manufacturers of lemonade in Georgia:

[Kazbegi](http://www.kazbegi.com/?sec_id=9&lang_id=ENG)

[Natakhtari](http://www.natakhtari.ge/?action=page&page_id=68&pageon=68&lang=eng)

Does it look familiar?

There is also [Zandukeli](http://castel.ge/index2.php?newsid=16)

Comment: Ah yes Natakhtari was always around during my visit to Tbilisi last year. But I see neither site has the violet bottle Roflcopter described...

Comment: Zandukeli also seems to come in clear bottles.

Answer (score 2):

Giorgi already mentioned Zandukeli (ზანდუკელი) but here's a photo of a bottle I drank in a local restaurant a few days ago.

The bottle was clear but the lemonade was violet. It didn't taste like Sprite though, it was grape flavour. In fact a local Georgian grape variety called saperavi (საფერავი), which makes it quite unique.

[image: საფერავი ზანდუკელი]
<sup>Sorry it's blurry and not colour-accurate. I took it without flash and the lighting was quite dim.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think the name is Zedazeni I also tried the drink myself it was very tasty